# defining a variable in dynamic-type languages

Tags: python

is there somewhere that you have to define a type in dynamic type programming language ?

[image]

I know that , we can use 'else number=default' . but it is just a example to Show Ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic and static languages both require "definition". Dynamic languages often don't need a "declaration". A definition is when you actually create the variable. A declaration is some formal way of saying that "from now on, this variable exists" - like `int n;` in C.

In Python, the definition happens on assignment. The use happens when you try to get the value of the variable(also called dereferencing). You can't use a variable without defining it and that's why you see this error.

Some languages like perl have, what they call [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification). This means that if you use a variable without defining it, it will automatically get defined for you. In that case, this program will behave differently. The value of `number` will be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is `3`, so `number` isn't defined yet, since it's missed by your if-else ladder.

If you don't want a "catch-all" else condition, then just assign a `number = 'default'` before your if-else ladder.

Answer (score 1):

Typing of a language does not have anything to do with the error you are getting.

Dynamic Typing means that names/variables are not bound to a specific type at compile time. We can make the same name point to different *types* of objects in the same program (at different lines ofcourse). But it does not mean that you can access a name/variable before its defined.

The error you are getting is because the name/variable is not defined at all. Also, rather than defining `number` in `else`, it seems easier to define `number` to some default value before the `if..elif` block.